Type hint for optionally-empty set and dict
I have a function that can return either an empty set or a set of strings: {'string1', 'string2'}. How would I type hint this? Would set[str] allow an empty set?
Similarly, what would be the type hint for a function that can return either an empty dict or a dict with strings as keys and bool or string or list of strings as values? Does dict[str, str|bool|List[str]] allow empty dicts?

Duplicate: Type hint for a list of string with 0 or more items in python. It's about list, but the same applies to set and dict.

set[str] allows an empty set. For cases where you want to force non-empty set at type hint level, you can do tuple[str, set[str]]. However, logic to replicate set.contains and such would be more complicated.

Formally, {} has type set[T] for an unconstrained type variable T. That is, its type is polymorphic. (You can think of this as there being multiple, distinct empty set values, one per monormophic type, which at runtime are all represented by a unique set value.)

Why not just try it?

At the type level, there is no difference between an empty set and a non-empty set. The only thing special about the empty set is that it is simultaneously an empty set[str], an empty set[int], etc.

set[str] will be perfectly fine! You can test it yourself with a code sample like this:
x: set[str]
x = set()
x = {"fizz"}
x = {0}

mypy will yell at you for the last assignment since you passed in an set[int] instead of a set[str], but the first one is totally okay.
Same goes for the dictionary. The following snippet will pass static type checking:
from typing import List

x: dict[str, str|bool|List[str]] = {}


You can handle your situation like this by using optional type form the typing
Here is the example:
def my_function() -> set[str] | None:
    # ...

def my_function() -> dict[str, Union[str, bool, list[str]]] | None:
    # ...

Or you can try something like this as well.
from typing import Optional, set

def my_function() -> Optional[set[str]]:
    # ...


Your examples are swapped; Python 3.9 requires Union, while Python 3.10 and later allow for unions defined with the | operator.

This doesn't answer the actual question, though, which is based on the mistaken assumption that a concrete set type doesn't include the empty set.

Yes, you are right, I have updated my solution.

Optional[set[str]] does not permit the empty set which set[str] already does; it allows the additional non-set value None.
